# error while running java file which need .jar file

Tags: java, jar, noclassdeffounderror

i had a file called Simple.java and it uses packages which are present in netcdfAll-            4.2jar and i had compiled it successfully but when i tried to run it im getting error message like 
      exception in thread main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: I would advise that you expand your question because you're not providing enough information for anyone to realistically help you. This usually leads to a protracted and frustrating round of requests in the comments for more information by other users who **really do want to help you**. For example, include in the question: code snippets/samples, the API you're using, stack traces, screen shots etc. When you've done this, flag to have your question re-opened. Please also take the time to [read this](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing your exact command, you maybe missing the classpath. When running your code using the java command use -cp (classpath) option like this (assuming Linux):

```
java -cp .:<path>/netcdfAll-4.2jar Simple
```

put all required jars as a colon separated list to the -cp switch

Read this [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29#Setting_the_path_to_execute_Java_programs) for details

Comment: Hi aditya I am running in windows environment and i had my jars and java files in same folder

Comment: For windows use semi colon as the separator, like java -cp .;.\netcdfAll-4.2jar Simple